# Reliably working out if your db is down with Scala Slick

Tags: scala, jdbc, slick

I am using Scala slick to work with my Mysql db.

I am wrapping all the calls using scala.util.Try

I would like to have different behaviour based on the problem

- If the DB is down, ultimately I want my webapp to return a 503
- If a strange query gets through to my db layer and there is a bug with my code then I want to return a 500

After some googling, it seems like you can get a wide array of different exceptions with error codes and I'm unsure what to look for.

With slick i am using the com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slick/MySQL will throw `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` for bad syntax and `CommunicationsException` when it's unable to reach the database.

Here's a quick example that will catch both of these types of exceptions:

```
try {
    Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://some-host:3306/db-name", 
                    driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", 
                    user="", 
                    password="") withSession { session: Session =>
      implicit val s = session
      ...
    }
} catch {
    case e: MySQLSyntaxErrorException =>
        ... handle the syntax error ...
        // You may want to define your own Exception that wraps the MySQL one
        // and adds more context
    case e: CommunicationsException =>
        ... handle the connection error ...
}
```

Then, in your webapp code, you'll want to catch your custom exceptions (see the comment in the code) and return the HTTP codes accordingly.